# Search strings that have a specific prefix xxx*

Tags: mysql, ios, database

In my data base, I have a field `date_ID` with a strings as follows:

```
  ----------------------------------
+              date_ID              +
  ----------------------------------
  111-11-333   555+33+22    -00000
  111-22-333   555+33+22    -00569      -- > element 1
  111-05-333   555+33+22    -00789
  111-22-333   555+33+22    -00008      -- > element 2
  111-22-333   555+33+22    -00001      -- > element 3
  111-22-111   555+33+22    -00001      -- > element 4
  ----------------------------------
```

How can I select all `date_ID` strings, that contains `111-22` as the prefix?

Table is dynamic. I'm new to mySql, so please help.

**UPDATED QUESTION**

I'm doing it in iOS, so I'm confused with the syntax too. So, pls help me to get the string as the form below.

```
NSString *passedPrefix = @"111-22";
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from my_table WHERE date_ID LIKE \"%@\"",passedPrefix]
// How to add that last '%' here?
```

Comment: In future make sure you have a reasonable search before posting. Simply searching **"mysql select strings with prefix"** on Google found the above question on this website that would have answered your question.

Comment: ok, But how to concant the last '%' with my string ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date_id LIKE '111-22%'
```

Comment: thanks for the support. But how to concant the last '%' with my string ?

Comment: @Thampuran, check my answer for iOS implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In normal SQL you would use:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date_ID LIKE '111-22%'
```

But as you've asked how to use this in iOS `stringWithFormat`, I **think** this is how:

```
WHERE date_ID LIKE '%@%%'
```

According to my source, you don't need to escape with backslashes.

I know nothing about iOS development, I literally did a Google search for you.